# Make a python cProfile script to profile another python script contained in a different directory

Tags: python, cprofile

I'm trying to make a module that lets you do basically the same PyCharm professional edition does, take a profile snapshot during the program execution, but as a module instead of a whole UI

In order to do so i was trying to first make a script that receives a path to another script and prints the later script's profile (i will always assume that the later script has a **main**).

Here is what i got:

```
import cProfile
import imp

pr = cProfile.Profile()
pr.disable()
def profileScript(script):
    pr.enable()
    pr.run('script')
    pr.disable()
    pr.print_stats()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    script = imp.load_source('meihn','A:\TestProgram\meihn.py')
    profileScript(script)
```

and the test script i'm profiling:

```
def func1(a,b):
    return a + b

def func2(lista, listb):
    listc = []
    for i in range(0, len(lista)):
        listc.append(func1(lista[i],listb[i]))
    return listc

def func3(list):
    a = 1
    for i in list:
        a *= i
    return a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(0, 1000):
        la = [1, 2, 3, 4]
        lb = [5, 5, 5, 5]

        lc = func2(la, lb)

        ld = func2(la, lc)
        le = func2(lb, lc)

     input()

     for i in range(0, 10000):
          lf = func3(le)

     input()
```

It runs but the it doesn't stop at the inputs and the result is the following:

```
         5 function calls in 0.000 seconds

Ordered by: standard name

    ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 cProfile.py:132(run)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 cProfile.py:137(runctx)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'enable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}



Process finished with exit code 0
```

Which basically tells me it didn't call any of the functions from meihn.py, i soppose that's because it didn't call the main for some reason.

Any comment on this as well as on how to do the async snapshooting would be of great help.

I'm using python 2.7

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to break it to you, but your test script does not have any main function that could be called. :-)

Anyway, I get the same results for my script, which has a main function. I suppose that the profiler just cannot "see through" your calling mechanism.

By looking into `cProfile.py`, I came up with the following solution:

```
import os
import sys
import cProfile

pr = cProfile.Profile()
pr.disable()


def profile_script(progname):
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(progname))
    with open(progname, 'rb') as fp:
        code = compile(fp.read(), progname, 'exec')
    globs = {
        '__file__': progname,
        '__name__': '__main__',
        '__package__': None,
    }

    pr.enable()
    pr.runctx(code, globs, None)
    pr.disable()
    pr.print_stats()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    profile_script('A:\TestProgram\meihn.py')
```

Also, I modified your test script a bit, because using `input` with `exec` will result in a syntax error:

```
def func1(a, b):
    return a + b


def func2(lista, listb):
    listc = []
    for i in range(0, len(lista)):
        listc.append(func1(lista[i],listb[i]))
    return listc


def func3(list):
    a = 1
    for i in list:
        a *= i
    return a


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(0, 1000):
        la = [1, 2, 3, 4]
        lb = [5, 5, 5, 5]

        lc = func2(la, lb)

        ld = func2(la, lc)
        le = func2(lb, lc)

    raw_input('input: ')

    for i in range(0, 10000):
        lf = func3(le)

    raw_input('input: ')
```

This gives me:

```
         43098 function calls in 11.249 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Queue.py:107(put)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Queue.py:204(_put)
        1    0.000    0.000   11.249   11.249 cProfile.py:137(runctx)
        1    0.023    0.023   11.249   11.249 meihn.py:1(<module>)
    12000    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 meihn.py:1(func1)
    10000    0.010    0.000    0.010    0.000 meihn.py:12(func3)
     3000    0.030    0.000    0.035    0.000 meihn.py:5(func2)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.000 pydev_console_utils.py:145(__pydev_run_command)
        2    0.000    0.000   11.180    5.590 pydev_console_utils.py:154(readline)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 pydevd_comm.py:427(add_command)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 pydevd_comm.py:567(__init__)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 pydevd_comm.py:843(make_input_requested_message)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 pydevd_utils.py:69(is_string)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 pydevd_utils.py:72(to_string)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 pydevd_utils.py:86(quote_smart)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 threading.py:299(_is_owned)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 threading.py:372(notify)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 threading.py:63(_note)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 urllib.py:1248(quote)
        8    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {isinstance}
     3000    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {len}
        8    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'acquire' of 'thread.lock' objects}
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'append' of 'collections.deque' objects}
    12000    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'enable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        2   11.179    5.590   11.179    5.590 {method 'readline' of 'file' objects}
        7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'release' of 'thread.lock' objects}
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'remove' of 'list' objects}
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'rstrip' of 'str' objects}
     3002    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {range}
        2    0.001    0.000   11.181    5.590 {raw_input}
```